# Installation unsuccessful: Chocolatey installation on VS Code via CMD / Power Shell

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, chocolatey, choco

I was installing node.js and, during the installation, was given the option to also install Chocolatey. The first issue was, it didn't install. The error will be attached below.

I then ran CMD as **an administrator** and wrote `choco upgrade -y visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`
This, also, did not solve the issue. I rather got the same error message, which is -

> **ERROR: Unable to detect any supported Visual Studio product. You may try passing --installPath or both --productId and --channelId parameters.**
>
> **The upgrade of visualstudio2019-workload-vctools was NOT successful.**
>
> **Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.**
>
> **See log for details.**
>
> **Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.**
>
> **See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).**
>
> **Failures**
>
> **- visualstudio2019-workload-vctools (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.**
>
> **See log for details.**

Attempts:

- To install automatically, failed
- To install by running CMD as **an administrator** and writing `choco upgrade -y visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`
- Uninstalled node.js and repeated the first step.

Expectation:

- To install Chocolatey, failed regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install Chocolatey CLI using `nodejs`. Install Chocolatey CLI on it's own.

The other error you got tells you what the issue is:

```
ERROR: Unable to detect any supported Visual Studio product. You may try passing --installPath or both --productId and --channelId parameters.
```

It can't detect any *supported* Visual Studio product, so perhaps you don't have one installed?

Comment: thanks for the input. However, it is important to note that, I do have Visual Studio Code and have been regularly using it, pushing commits and what not. But I still couldn't figure out CMD would say 
`ERROR: Unable to detect any supported Visual Studio product. You may try passing --installPath or both --productId and --channelId parameters.`